# String Loop in Assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, loops, assembly

I have to create a loop that will have the end result that prints out "LoopLoopLoopLoopLoop" (note only 5 times). What I have so far is this..

```
.data
STRING_1  DB  "Loop"

.code
mov ecx, 5  ; Perform loop 5 times
printLoop:
    LEA DX, STRING_1
    loop printLoop
call DumpRegs
```

I'm not even 100% sure if what I have is even correct but I suppose the main question I have is how do I make it so that all of the outcomes are printed on the same line?

Comment: _"I'm not even 100% sure if what I have is even correct"_. Run it and see what happens? By the looks of it your code currently doesn't print the string at all, because you've added no code to print it. As for how to get the output on one line - just don't print any linefeed characters.

Comment: Well it says that it failed to build and what code would I add to print it? How do you even print things in assembly? sorry I am kinda still new to this stuff

Comment: _" it says that it failed to build"_ Then you need to go through all the error messages you're getting and fix whatever problems they're referring to. _"How do you even print things in assembly"_ See the documentation for whatever library you're using (Irvine?).

Comment: "How do you print" - it's different for every platform, so don't spend too much time memorizing it, just find your target platform API description and use it, or some library functions (looks like irvine lib from the `call DumpRegs`)... just read through API 1-2 times to get idea what is there, and then have the docs by hand to check details every time you are using some of it.